How do I pass JSON to a Postgres COPY tmp FROM PROGRAM command
I'm trying to use Postgres (PL/pgSQL) to communicate with a shell script that expects JSON data. A simplified example of what I'm trying to do is
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION json_func(IN json_in JSONB, OUT json_out JSONB)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $code_block$
BEGIN
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp (json_tmp JSONB);
EXECUTE format($bash$ COPY tmp FROM PROGRAM 'echo ''%s'' | jq . ' $bash$, json_in);
SELECT json_tmp FROM tmp INTO json_out;
DROP TABLE tmp;
END;
$code_block$;

When I run
SELECT json_func('{"key1": "val1", "key2": "val2"}'::JSONB);

I get
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
DETAIL:  The input string ended unexpectedly.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: {
COPY tmp, line 1, column json_tmp: "{"
SQL statement " COPY tmp FROM PROGRAM 'echo ''{"key1": "val1", "key2": "val2"}'' | jq . ' "
PL/pgSQL function json_func(jsonb) line 4 at EXECUTE

I've tried various ways of escaping the single quotes needed to surround the JSON input, but no luck.

I think that the trouble is that your bash script 'echo ''%s'' | jq . ' is not returning a valid postgres json. You can test that the input is right with insert into tmp values ('{"key1": "val1", "key2": "val2"}'::JSONB);

Try using jq -c . to avoid pretty printing the json

You're getting the error because COPY expects one value per line, while jq pretty-prints by default, splitting the single json structure into multiple lines. As already pointed out by @Francisco Puga, you can disable that:

--compact-output / -c:
By default, jq pretty-prints JSON output. Using this option will result in more compact output by instead putting each JSON object on a single line.

Otherwise, this
'{"key1": "val1", "key2": "val2"}'

Gets turned by jq into this
{
    "key1": "val1",
    "key2": "val2"
}

And due to the line-separation thing, copy thinks you're trying to do something this:
insert into tmp(json_tmp)values 
 ('{')
,('"key1": "val1",')
,('"key2": "val2"')
,('}');

Hence, the error complaining about the single opening curly bracket. It seems to work fine if you enable compaction:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION json_func(IN json_in JSONB, OUT json_out JSONB)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $code_block$
BEGIN
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp (json_tmp JSONB);
EXECUTE format($dynsql$ COPY tmp FROM PROGRAM $bash$echo %1$L |jq -c . $bash$ 
               $dynsql$, json_in);
SELECT json_tmp FROM tmp INTO json_out;
DROP TABLE tmp;
END;
$code_block$;


If that's an attempt to pretty-print, Postgres offers a built-in jsonb_pretty():
demo at db<>fiddle
select jsonb_pretty('{"abc":123}');




jsonb_pretty




{    "abc": 123}



If it's for validation, In version 16+ you can check that with 'abc' IS JSON or pg_input_is_valid('abc','jsonb'):
select 'abc' is json;                          --false
select pg_input_is_valid('abc','json');        --false
select '{"abc":123}' is json;                  --true
select pg_input_is_valid('{"abc":123}','json');--true


jq -c . was the magic incantation! Many thanks for the prompt help.
